# Fetching model objects with distinct column values

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4

I have an `applications` table, containing `user_id`, `email`, `phone`, etc.. An applicant may or may not create a user account, because registration is optional; hence `user_id` is nullable. They might also apply multiple times with the same email address, in which case `email` in `applications` table would be duplicated across several records.

Now, the objective is to fetch all `Application` model instances excluding duplicates. EX: if Jack applied five times with `jack@gmail.com`, the `applications` table would have 5 records with `email` column set to `jack@gmail.com`. When fetching `Application`s, I'd like to get only one record with `jack@gmail.com`, the other four should be ignored.

So, I tried multiple approaches, but they either fetched all records or didn't execute at all:

1. `groupBy('email')` fails with `get()` because of non-aggreagated column `email`:

   `Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'applications.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

   At the same time, `groupBy('email')->get(['email'])` works well, but the problem is that I need other columns too (`created_at` at least), ideally - the full `Application` model instance.
2. `Application::whereIn('id', function($query) { $query->select('id')->groupBy('email'); })->get()` returns all records from the table
3. `Application::select('*', 'DISTINCT email')->get()` results in

   `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'DISTINCT email' in 'field list'`

   The Eloquent approach `Application::distinct()->get(['email'])` gives the proper list of emails, but once again, I need more columns that just the email. Once I start selecting more columns, I keep getting all records as results.
4. All of the following queries fail due to the strict mode being enabled:

   - `SELECT * FROM (  SELECT * FROM applications ORDER BY id DESC ) AS tmp GROUP BY email`
   - `SELECT * FROM applications WHERE id IN(SELECT id FROM applications GROUP BY email)`
   - `SELECT email, id, created_at from ( SELECT  email, id, created_at FROM applications) apps group by email`

Can anyone help me to figure out the proper approach? I'd love to use Eloquent and work with actual models, rather than `stdObj` or other, if Eloquent can accommodate my problem/limitations.

P.S. The SQL engine I'm using is **MySQL** with strict mode enabled.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you want to put an expression inside your eloquent you must use `DB::raw('DISTINCT email')` for that.

Second, I believe you should go with this approach:

```
Application::select('id', 'email', 'more_fields')->groupBy('email')->get();
```

You must have the column you group by it in your `select()` function.

Last option:

You can just use the `->distinct()` function on your eloquent query to remove duplicates.